# How can I find the page number from a .pdf by a text?

Tags: r, pdf, text

I have a .pdf with 120 certificates, each page is a certificate and the only difference is the name of the participant.

I also have a .csv with the name and e-mail (I will also try to send by e-mail with R later).

How can I split each certificate (page) and save in a new .pdf with the participant name?

I saw functions like `pdf_subset` from `library(pdftools)`, but how can I identify the page number by some text?

```
# extract some pages
pdf_subset('https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf',
  pages = 1:3, output = "subset.pdf")
```

Example of .pdf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iwgW6kMT7C9Xee5SM65vz-D8B26bpavz/view?usp=sharing

in the .csv I have the column name

```
name,
Prof. Dr. Thiado Souza,
Prof. Dr. Marcelo Jose ́,
Ricado Augusto,
Carlos Jose ́,
```

Answer (score 1):

`pdf_text` returns a character vector where each element represents individual page.

```
library(pdftools)
data <- pdf_text('https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf')
```

`data[1]` is the 1st page of the pdf, `data[2]` is the second one and so on. So you can subset one page at a time or multiple pages like `data[1:10]` for first 10 pages.